# Why textarea doesnt display real value of formControl if i use matAutocomplete

Tags: angular, angular-material

```
  <textarea
  matInput
  type="text" class="send-message-input"
  [disabled]="isTypingNotAvailable"
  [rows]="rowsCount"
  placeholder="Type text ..."
  formControlName="text"
  (keydown.control.enter)="onCtrlEnter()"
  (keydown.enter)="onEnter($event)"
  [matAutocomplete]="auto"
></textarea>
```

When i call this code:

```
this.sendMessageForm.get('text').setValue('Hi');
```

I see how the given text is placed in the form, but in the textarea (visually) it is not displayed, why?

see that https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-plhchb?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: If possible, try to reproduce the problem in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) or a similar site.

Comment: look, u can add text (click btn) and see on console result if u click to show text in form https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-plhchb?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Interesting, I see the same behaviour with a textbox `<input>` element as well (so I guess textarea is not the culprit). Upon clicking "Add text" button, a new value is set and it clears the text content. I think you want it not clear and display the updated value instead.

Comment: yes, i wanna se new text vissually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `displayWith` property on the `mat-autocomplete` component is preventing the control value from being set programmatically with a plain string.

The `displayFn` callback function provided is preventing the form control from being set with a plain string. You could either remove the `displayWith` property, or update the `displayFn` to allow a plain string to be set, or set the control value using an object `{value: 'my string'}` instead of a string.

**1. Remove the `displayWith` property from the autocomplete component.**

```
//template

<mat-autocomplete 
    #auto="matAutocomplete" 
    [displayWith]="displayFn" <-- remove
>
```

**2. Update the `displayFn` method to allow your manual changes.**

```
// component.ts

  displayFn(template): string {
    return template && template.value ? template.value : template;
  }
```

**3. Update the `control.setValue()` method to work with the `displayFn`.**

Set the control value by pass in an object with i.e., `control.setValue({value: 'my string'})`.

```
// component.ts

  initForm() {
    this.sendMessageForm = this.fb.group({
      test: [{value: 'Initial text'}],  <-- need to use object {value: 'string'}
    });
  }

  ...

  addText() {
    this.sendMessageForm?.get('test').setValue({value: 'hi'});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not about textarea or setting value.
It is about matAutocomplete directive on it.
So I removed the directive and the problem is gone.
It seems textarea is not compatible with matAutocomplete.

Comment: This fixed the issue. `It seems textarea is not compatible with matAutocomplete.` - this isn't true. I found the same behaviour on `<input>` text box as well.

Comment: yes, thanks. let me take a closer look.

Comment: I cant remove matAutocomplete directive

Comment: it's not answer

Comment: Yes, I was not able to comment. I'm working on it.